# Is is possible to use two kernels at the same time?

Tags: grub2, kernel, compiling

After upgrading from `Ubuntu 13.04` to `Ubuntu 13.10` `Intel VTune Amplifier` stopped working.
As recommeded by developer I tried to reinstall the program and manually compile the needed drivers. However I got some compilation errors, so my next thought was to boot to previous kernel (by restarting and choosing `Advanced options` from grub menu) and compile and run `VTune` under it. Now when trying to compile I am facing this error:

`ERROR: invalid or inaccessible kernel source directory "/usr/src/linux-3.5.0-34-generic" !`

and when trying to get the header files, I am facing this:

`E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.5.0-34-generic`

So is it at all possible to boot to the old kernel to run some programs and otherwise use the new kernel ?
And if so, how could I solve my problem above ?

Comment: Yes, you can install multiple kernels at the same time and boot any one of them every the machine boots. Of course you *cannot use them simultaneously*.

Comment: Almost all installs end up with multiple kernels, you just end up using the latest unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use multiple kernels AT the same time. But you can have multiple kernels on your machine and chose in grub what kernel version you want to use.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirmation, but now I have a second question.
The linux kernel I am using right now is `3.5.0-34-generic`, but when I search for linux headers of this version in aptitude, I get no results. Searching on my machine, I found headers for `3.5.0-27-generic`. Do you think I can use these for compilation, or should I rather find those that match exactly ?

Comment: So if anyone else wondered, I found the linux kernel headers here: [http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/) and downloaded and installed these deb packages: `linux-headers-3.5.0-34-generic_3.5.0-34.55_i386.deb` and `linux-headers-3.5.0-34_3.5.0-34.55_all.deb` (I have a 32-bit system).